# io_uring in multithreaded process

Tags: c, linux, io-uring

I am trying to write a multithreaded server using `io_uring`.
The problem is the function 'io_uring_wait_cqe' requires calling to `io_uring_cqe_seen` to mark the CQE as seen.

Therefore, in several threads, there may be a situation where the same event is handled in several threads.

Of course, I don't want to use locks, mutex, etc.

What is the best way to work with several threads?

Comment: To be clear: you mean thread 1 calls io_uring_wait_cqe and gets CQE 1, and thread 2 calls io_uring_wait_cqe and also gets CQE 1 because thread 1 hasn't marked it as seen?

Comment: @user253751 Yes.

Comment: > of course, I don't want to use locks, mutex, etc. -- Why not? This seems like the obvious approach to this issue

Comment: Because this is not the most efficient way. I'm looking for something like EPOLLONESHOT in EPOLL

Answer (score 0):

the official suggestion from jens axboe is to prefer to use [one io_uring per thread.](https://github.com/axboe/liburing/issues/571#issuecomment-1106480309)
If for some reason you really need thread synchronization an approach could be to have one worker thread that uses io_uring, and other threads use message passing to talk with the working thread.